# Обувь, носимая в зимнее время, в плохую погоду

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подберите противоположное по смыслу выражение.

Легкая обувь -...

Comment: Теплоизолирующая?

Comment: "зимняя обувь" обычно говорят

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"в зимнее время" - теплая обувь,
"в плохую погоду" - непромокаемая обувь.

Даже не представляю что тут можно ещё придумать, прямого антонима для "легкая обувь" в русском языке нет.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант противоположного "ненастью и зиме": **повседневная демисезонная** обувь.

https://www.ecco-shoes.ru/men/shoes/all/demiseason/filter/casual/

Если нужен обратный антоним - **всепогодная** обувь:
https://www.slamdunk.su/content/view/372